# Memory Leaks and Apache

Tags: linux, apache, memory-leaks

My VPS account has been occasionally running out of memory. It's using Apache on Linux. Support says it's a slow memory leak and has enabled MaxRequestsPerChild to deal with it.

I have a few questions about this. When a child process dies, will it cause my scripts to lose session data? Does anyone have advice on how I can track down this memory leak?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, when a child process dies you will not lose any data unless it was in the middle of a request at the time (which should not happen if it exits due to MaxRequestsPerChild).

You should try to reproduce the memory leak using an identical software stack on your test system. You can use tools such as Valgrind to try to detect it.

You can also try a debug build of your web server and its modules, which will enable you to detect what's going on.

It's difficult to reproduce the behaviour of production systems in non-production ones. If you have auto-test coverage of your web application, you could try using your full auto-test suite, but in practice this is unlikely to cover every code path therefore may miss the leaky one.

Answer (score 0):

> When a child process dies, will it cause my scripts to lose session data?

**Without knowing what scripting language and session handler you are using (and the actual code) it rather hard to say.**

In most cases, using scripting languages in modules or via [fast] cgi, then its very unlikely that the session data would actually be lost - although if the process dies in the middle of processing a request it may not get the chance to write the updated session back to whatever is storing the session. And in the very unlikely event it dies during the writeback, it may corrupt the session data. These are quite exceptional circumstances.

OTOH if your application logic is implemented via a daemon (e.g. a Java container) then its quite probable that memory leaks could accumulate (although these would be reported against a different process).

Note that if the problem is alleviated by setting MaxRequestsPerChild then it implies that the problem is occurring in an Apache module.

The production releases of Apache itself, in my experience, is very stable without memory leaks. However I've not used all the modules. Not sure if ExtendedStatus gives a breakdwon of memory usage by module - might be worth checking.

I've previously seen problems with the memory management of modules loaded by the PHP module not respecting PHP's memory limits - these did clear down at the end of the request though.

C.